# Firebase Cloud function Temp Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I made a cloud function in Firebase that resizes images. Therefore, I download the image and save it in the temp storage.

```
const tmp = require('tmp-promise');
const { path: tmpDirPath } = await tmp.dir();
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp-promise

The firebase documentation says "Always delete temporary files".
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#write_idempotent_functions

Does this package do this automatically or is there a specific code I should run?
Will this interfere if the function gets triggered multiple times (having multiple instances each converting a picture at the same time)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That library would have no way of knowing when it's time to delete any files it creates.  Only you know that, and you'll have to code your function to delete those files just before the function terminates, and the files are no longer in use.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you very much! But imagine the following scenario: 2 users trigger the function at almost the same time (1000ms difference). If the first instance is completed, it wipes the temp storage. Would this give an error to the second instance that is converting at that time and thus relying on temp storage at that time? Or are instances separated from each other?

Comment: That's not the way it works.  A server instance allocated to a function will only execute functions in serial.  There is no concurrency or multithreading when it comes to functions.  When load gets high enough, a more server instances will be allocated, and they won't share tmp space.